# Sort() - Python

Tags: python

Boa noite galera, estou comecando no python e estou com uma duvida que não consigo pensar em uma solucao... fiz um codigo para gerar 6 numeros em uma lista e imprimir sem repetir nenhum item porem ordenados crescentemente. usei o metodo sort() sem sucesso tentei reordenar os objetos em outra lista também com o sorted(lista)
e ambos deram errado[Não ordenaram no print], uma coisa que achei interessante é que quando eu executo os testes no prompt do python sem o sort() parece que apenas o set() já ordena os numeros...
[![codigo

```
from random import randint
import msvcrt
def gerar (quantidade):
    for i in range(0,quantidade):
        jogada = {}
        numeros = []
        while len(jogada) < 6:
            numeros.append(randint(1, 60))
            numeros.sort() # Pq não funciona??
            jogada = set(numeros)
        print('Jogo numero {n}: {j}'.format(n = i+1, j = jogada) )
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch().decode() == chr(27):
            break
#->
gerar(int(input('Numero de jogos: ')))
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uhIY.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uhIY.png)
[[image: executando teste da 'anomalia' hahaha ou nao...]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUMjp.png)

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava no set, conjuntos em python são estruturas desordenadas, "a indexação não tem significado ao ponto de que não se pode acessar um elemento de um conjunto set pelo index", então mesmo o sort estando ordenando sua lista quando é executado o "jogada = set(numeros)" o conjunto passa a ficar desordenado, a solução que encontrei foi converter o jogada para uma lista e depois fazer o sort nele.

```py
from random import randint
import msvcrt
def gerar (quantidade):
    for i in range(0,quantidade):
        jogada = {}
        numeros = []
        while len(jogada) < 6:
            numeros.append(randint(1, 60))
            jogada = set(numeros)
        jogada = list(jogada)
        jogada.sort()
        print('Jogo numero {n}: {j}'.format(n = i+1, j = jogada) )
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch().decode() == chr(27):
            break
#->
gerar(int(input('Numero de jogos: ')))
```

Também sou novato em python mas espero ter ajudado.